# ZipArchive :: close() not working in CentOS

Tags: php, linux, centos

```
<?php
$zips = new ZipArchive();
$ZipFileName = "zip_face.zip";
$res = $zips->open($ZipFileName, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE);
if ( $res === TRUE) {
    $zips->addFromString('ziptest.php', 'ziptest.php');
    if($zips->close()){
        echo 'created';
    }else{
        echo 'failed';
    }
}
?>
```

**Output :**

> Warning: ZipArchive::close(): Failure to create temporary file: Permission denied in /var/www/html/ziptest.php on line 7
>       failed

```
<?php
$zips = new ZipArchive();
$ZipFileName = "/tmp/zip_face.zip";
$res = $zips->open($ZipFileName, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE);
if ( $res === TRUE) {
    $zips->addFromString('ziptest.php', 'ziptest.php');
    if($zips->close()){
        echo 'created';
    }else{
        echo 'failed';
    }
}
?>
```

output: created

> no zip file found in /tmp folder

Note: all permission is given in both folders recursively.

Thanks in advance

Comment: have you tried using `chmod` on that folder? what's the version of your PHP?

Comment: any help on this, i'm facing the same issue